# How to Rotate Normally in Blender?

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

I have an object that is slanted on all 3 axes, and I need to rotate its bottom  on its own axis. I used the word *normally* because that's how this function would be called in *Wings 3D* software.

Comment: Are you looking for **Local** [Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#orientations)?

Comment: It would help if you show images of actually object in question. See how to include https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: No need, Leander answered my question. Thank you!